# Unable to Save When Setting Value in Required Text Field Through IE COM Object

Tags: html, powershell

When setting the value attribute of a text field I am unable to save the page. If I type it in the value, it doesn't show the value updated in the HTML but it allows me to save. Should I be looking at a different way of processing this value change? Is there a way to view what .JS is doing in the background when I hit save?

HTML

```
<input class="GAFVGA5C-H GAFVGA5IYH cw_CwTextField cw_PsaSummaryHeader" style="width: 150px;" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="" value="">
```

POWERSHELL

```
Function CheckClass($ie, $e, $s){

    return $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName($e) | Where {$_.ClassName -match $s}
}

#create summary
#ISSUE: unable to save value
$summary = CheckClass -ie $ie -e "input" -s "GAFVGA5C-H GAFVGA5IYH cw_CwTextField cw_PsaSummaryHeader"
$summary.value = $in_summary
```

EDIT: modified code to reflect comments

Comment: `-contains` is the wrong operator to use for substring matching, `$summary` has got to be `$null`, right? Try `-match` or `-eq` instead.

Comment: It seems to grab the object, but it doesn't seem to update the 'value'. this is part of what appears when I call on `$summary`:
`className                    : GAFVGA5C-H GAFVGA5IYH cw_CwTextField 
                               cw_PsaSummaryHeader...`